# how to change the button text programmaticaly in gwt

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I want change the text inside `iButton` in Gwt in programmatically without using css. Please help.

```
IButton stretchButton = new IButton("Stretch Button");
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways:

```
((Button)event.getSource()).setValue("x");
```

Or

Outside the ***handler***, use

```
Final Button btn = button;
```

Then you will be able to use **btn** as reference to the button inside the ***handler*** .

Answer (score 0):

Once you instanced the button:

```
IButton b = new IButton("IButton1");
```

Setting the tittle will make the text in the button change.

```
b.setTitle("new Tittle");
```